# Wie schreibt man ein langgezogenes "ie"?

Tags: spelling, writing, written-language

Will man schriftlich darstellen, dass ein Wort besonders gedehnt ausgesprochen wird, vervielfältigt man einfach den entsprechenden Buchstaben.

Ein übertrieben gerolltes R wäre dann

> Rrrrrroulade

Ein langezogenes O

> Hallooooo, bzw. Halloooohoooo (wenn man den typischen Singsang darstellen will)

Oder dasselbe Wort mit einem langen A

> Haaaallo

usw.

Wie ist das allerdings bei der Kombination "[ie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehnungszeichen#Dehnungs-e_nach_i)"?

Googlet man z.B. jeweils nach den Begriffen Lieeebe vs. Liiiebe findet man nahezu die gleiche Anzahl Fundstellen (312.000, 318.000). Nieeemals und Niiiemals ergeben jeweils 10.600 und 45.200 Suchergebnisse.

Ich will mich nicht auf mein oder das "Gefühl" anderer verlassen und fand dazu auch nichts. Darum:

Gibt es entsprechende Rechtschreibregeln, wie man derart extrem gedehnte Worte schriftlich (z.B. Dialog in einem Buch) darstellen kann?

Wenn nicht, gibt es entsprechende Empfehlungen? (von Lektoren, Verlagen, Duden)

Wie stellt man so ein langgezogenes "ie" nach [IPA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Phonetisches_Alphabet) dar?

Comment: Es ist einigermaßen unwahrscheinlich, daß sich eine solche Regel finden läßt. Man könnte argumentieren, daß das "e" in "Liebe" ja kein gesprochener Laut ist (sondern nur ein Dehnungsmarker für das "i"), und sich deshalb eine Vervielfachung nicht weiter auf das "i" auswirkt. Oder genau andersrum. Nach den Rechtschreibregeln ist das "sowieso falsch" - Dort zu suchen ist also müßig.

Comment: @tofro Zwischen den beiden Argumentationen schwanke ich auch ^^. Ähnliches kann man auch bei iiih vs ihhh finden.

Answer (score 3):

In den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln findet sich dazu nichts und wird sich dazu niemals etwas finden lassen, denn sie behandeln den Standardfall der möglichst eindeutig geregelten Schreibweise von Wörtern. Gelegentlich lassen die amtlichen Regeln Varianten zu, in der Regel aber in Fällen, in denen kein lautlicher Unterschied besteht (also zum Beispiel ä versus e). In seltenen Fällen werden mit verschiedenen Schreibweisen verschiedene Aussprachen dargestellt, wie zum Beispiel bei Geschoss/Geschoß (letzteres österreichisch) – das jedoch stets innerhalb der üblichen Regeln.

Eine solche Verschriftlichung einer gedehnten Aussprache ist aber kein Phänomen, das im normalen geschriebenen Deutsch vorkommt. Es gibt keinen phonemischen Unterschied zwischen »Hallo« und »Halloooo« und es gibt keinen Grund, den Unterschied in einem förmlichen Schriftstück hervorheben zu wollen. Worum es sich handelt, ist eine Verschriftlichung der Umgangs- oder Alltagssprache, die, wie auch zum Beispiel in gewissen Verschleifungen wie »Hammer den schon zamgefaltet?«, sich grundsätzlich abseits der Regeln bewegt (wenngleich sie dennoch gerne auf die Kernpunkte der Regeln zurückgreift).

Auch die IPA-Schreibung ist für Regelfälle gedacht worden, und behandelt nicht umgangssprachliche, künstlich in die Länge gezogene Varianten. Es ist zwar möglich, das Längezeichen ː (zwei übereinander stehende Dreiecke die aufeinander zu zeigen) mehrmals hintereinander zu schreiben, um Überlänge darzustellen, meistens würde das aber für systematische Überlänge verwendet (Die [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length) bringt ein Beispiel aus dem Estnischen, wo anscheinend überlanges a in *saada* [saːːda] vorkommen kann). Für ein »Hallooooo« wie in deinem Beispiel sollten es wahrscheinlich drei oder vier Längezeichen sein.

Was Lektoren und Verlage betrifft: Ich würde stark vermuten, dass in dem Segment jeder seine eigenen Richtlinien hat – wenn sie überhaupt existieren. Der Haupteinsatzgebiete sind wahrscheinlich Belletristik und Comics; gerade in diesen Bereichen, in denen das Künstlerische im Vordergrund steht, könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass Autorinnen oder Autoren doch sehr auf genau ihrer eigenen Vorstellung, wie was geschrieben sein soll, beharren.

Dazu ein Beispiel: Ich erinnere mich an eine Talkshow zur Rechtschreibreform aus den 90ern, die uns unser Deutschlehrer im Grundkurs vorgespielt hat (der sogenannte *Rechtschreibrebell* war Deutschlehrer an meinem Gymnasium, daher hat dieses Video dort wahrscheinlich existiert). Ein Schriftsteller (männlich; seinen Namen habe ich vergessen) hat sich über eine Neuausgabe eines seiner Werke aufgeregt, denn darin wurde *Radfahren verboten* gemäß neuer Rechtschreibung als *Rad fahren verboten* geschrieben. Im Werk war beschrieben, dass dieser Text auf einem Schild stand, und sein Kommentar zur Neufassung war: »Aber das stand doch nicht auf dem Schild!« Dementsprechend denke ich, dass sich Verlage und Lektoren nicht in die Nesseln setzen wollen, etwas derart unstandardisiertes zu standardisieren.

Was bleibt also? Man kann nur seinen eigenen Weg gehen. Wie du an den Googlefundstellen siehst, scheinen beide Varianten etwa gleichverbreitet zu sein, und ich wüsste auch nicht, ob ich eine davon bevorzugen wollte, denn es ist ja nur ein Laut (ein Monophthong), der dummerweise durch zwei verschiedene Buchstaben dargestellt wird – das gleiche Problem wie bei überlangem *sch* oder *ch*. (Bei Diphthongen stellt sich die Frage meines Erachtens nicht, denn »Auuuuuuuutsch« und »Aaaaaaaußerdem« haben verschiedene gedehnte Vokale.) Ich müsste lügen, aber ich denke, dass ich beides schon mehrere Male verwendet habe, ohne groß darüber nachzudenken.

Es gibt noch eine andere Variante, die ich persönlich gerne verwende: Eine Tilde (~) verlängert den davor stehenden Laut. Beispiel: »Ach du lie~be Güte«. Auch das ist nichtstandardlich, aber es umgeht die Frage, ob ich jetzt das *i* oder das *e* vervielfältige.

Comment: Zu Diphthongen: Ich singe ja in einem Chor, und da kommt es mit großer Regelmäßigkeit vor, dass ein eigentlich kurzer Vokal oder ein Diphthong auf einer langen Note (manchmal sogar über mehrere Takte, also mehrere Sekunden lang) gesungen werden muss. Und da gilt die strikte Regel, dass bei Diphthongen IMMER der erst Laut zu dehnen ist. Der zweite wird erst ganz am allerletzten Ende der Note artikuliert. Daher gilt auch hier: Aaaaaaaaaaaautsch. Diese Regel gilt ganz sicher für Deutsch, Englisch und Latein. ...

Comment: ...  Ich erinnere mich aber auch daran, Texte in einer anderen Sprache (Hebräisch? Koreanisch? Russisch? ich weis es nicht mehr) gesungen zu haben, in der uns der Sprachcoach nahegelegt hat, den zweiten Vokal zu dehnen. Das war aber nur bei dieser einen Sprache der Fall, in allen anderen wird imemr der erste Vokal gedehnt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Was das Singen betrifft, magst du Recht haben. Trotzdem werde ich, wenn ich mir das Knie anhaue, eher »Auuuuuu!«, als »Aaaaaaau!«, sagen. Und dementsprechend würde ich das auch entsprechend als »Auuuuuu!« zum Beispiel in einen Chat schreiben.

Answer (score 2):

Der IPA-Teil lässt sich leicht beantworten.  Deutsch hat zwei Monophthonge, die mit <i>-bezogenen Graphemen notiert werden: /iː/, das lange <i> wie in <Liebe> (/liːbə/) und /ɪ/, das kurze <i> wie in <Lippe> (/lɪpə/). (Das Zeichen, das die Länge markiert, ist kein Doppelpunkt, sondern [zwei aufeinander zeigende Dreiecke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length), obwohl das natürlich oftsowohl schwer zu tippen als auch zu sehen ist).

"Phoneme" ist dabei in einem weniger exakten Sinne zu verstehen, da streng genommen die Länge eine suprasegmentale Eigenschaft ist, die aber in diesem Zusammenhang immer in Kombination mit dem phonologischen Kontrast vorkommt.  (Phoetisch gesehen kommt allerdings manchmal ein kurzes [i] als Allophon von [ɪ] vor; zB. kann man [kʀimiˈnɛl] so aussprechen.)

Extralängen können, wie @Jan mich erinnert hat, durch Wiederholung geschrieben werden: [liːːbə].  Allerdings ist das im Deutschen ein gewisser Missbrauch, da es sich nicht mehr um ein phonologisches Feature handelt (im Gegensatz zum Estnischen, das eine der wenigen Sprachen mit so etwas ist).

Notwendig ist eine Auszeichnung von Überlängen dagegen bei genauen Gesprächstrankriptionen für manche Zwecke; dafür existieren Transkriptionssysteme, von denen viele ad-hoc vom Anwender erfunden werden, aber auch standardisierte. [GAT](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gespr%C3%A4chsanalytisches_Transkriptionssystem) zB. ist Orthographie-basiert und verwendet wiederholte Doppelpunkte, aber nur bei längerer als der normalen Dehnung: `liebe` (normale Aussprache), `lie:be` (betont länger), `lie::be`, `lie:::be` (sehr stark verlängte Formen).

Comment: Kannst du für eines der obigen Worte so eine IPA-Notation vielleicht in die Antwort einfügen? :)

Comment: Natürlich. ----

Answer (score 2):

### Vorbemerkungen

Im geschriebenen Deutsch gibt es Signale, die die Verkürzung eines Vokals anzeigen, und Signale, die eine Verlängerung anzeigen.

**Verkürzung:**
Innerhalb derselben Silbe stehe zwei oder mehr Konsonanten hinter dem Vokal. Wenn hinter dem Vokal innerhalb derselben Silbe nur ein Konsonant gesprochen wird, wird dieser verdoppelt.

> Wal - Wall
> wen - wenn
> Haken - hacken
> Hasen - hassen
> kam - Kamm
> Qualen - Quallen
> usw.

Alle kurz (innerhalb derselben Silbe zwei oder mehr Konsonanten hinter dem Vokal):

> Pest, Strumpf, Kurt, Recht, Strich, Wort, ...

**Verlängerung:**
Um eine Verlängerung anzuzeigen, wird hinter dem Vokal ein Verlängerungszeichen eingefügt. Das kann eine Wiederholung desselben Buchstabens sein:

> Aal, Boot, See

Oder es kann ein spezielles Dehnungszeichen sein, das selbst nicht ausgesprochen wird. Dafür wird im Deutschen vor allem das *h* verwendet, das funktioniert nämlich bei allen Vokalen:

> Jahr, nah, Wahl
> mehr, sehr, zehn
> ihr, ihm, ihn
> ohne, wohl, Sohn
> Schuh, Stuhl, Huhn
> wählen, ähnlich, diesjährig
> fröhlich, Höhle, gewöhnen
> führen, früh, Bühne

Lediglich beim *i* gibt es auch eine andere Variante, nämlich dass hinterm dem zu verlängerndem Vokal der Buchstabe *e* geschrieben wird:

> die, wie, viel, bieten

Und um ganz sicher zu gehen, werden hinter einem *i* manchmal sogar *e* und *h* kombiniert:

> Vieh, nachvollziehbar, Fliehkraft

Wenn Verkürzung und Verlängerung aufeinandertreffen, gilt die Verlängerung:

> Biest, (zu) viert, Fahrt

Zu ergänzen ist, dass diese Regeln Ausnahmen haben, die einerseits sehr alte einsilbige Erbwörter (wie z.B. *"du", "wo", "(der) Weg"* (alle lang ohne Dehnungszeichen) aber ungedehnt in *"(ich muss) weg"*) aber auch viele Fremdwörter betreffen.

---

### Zur Frage

Man kann nun die Frage auch genereller stellen, anstatt sich nur auf ein langes *i* zu fokussieren:

> Wie kann man generell eine extreme Verlängerung eines gesprochenen Vokals in der Schriftform wiedergeben?

Nachdem wir damit auf jeden Fall die geltenden Rechtschreibregeln brechen werden, kann man sich natürlich auch nicht darauf berufen, aber man allgemeine Regeln erweitern, und diese mit dem allgemeinen Gebrauch vergleichen. Und da kommen eben in Frage:

> Vervielfachung des klingenden Vokals
> Vervielfachung des Dehnungszeichens

Wenn der klingende Vokal ohnehin schon im originalen Wort verdoppelt wird, wird man diesen Vokal auch weiter vervielfachen:

> Aaaaaaaal, Boooooooot, Seeeeeeee

Wenn man das Dehnungszeichens vervielfacht, erhält man in den meisten Fällen so etwas:

> Jahhhhhhr, mehhhhhhhr, ihhhhhhhr, Schuhhhhhhh usw.

So etwas habe ich noch nie gesehen. Daher würde ich auch in diesen Fällen den Vokal vervielfachen:

> Jaaaaaaahr, meeeeeeehr, iiiiiiiihr, Schuuuuuuuuh usw.

Und aus genau demselben Grund würde ich das auch bei *ie* und *ieh* machen:

> meine Empfehlung: diiiiiiie, biiiiiieten, Viiiiiiieh usw.
> Vermeiden würde ich dieeee, bieeeeeten, Vieeeeeh und Viehhhhhh

Ein weiterer Grund, der für die Vervielfachung des klingenden Vokals spricht, ist eben die Wiedergabe des Klangs. Wenn ich viele *e's* sehe, möchte ich im ersten Impuls ein langes *e* aussprechen, und bei vielen *h's* habe ich den Impuls einen langen Hauchlaut zu artikulieren.